# FullCalendar - eventDrop UTC Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, fullcalendar, momentjs

I've set up this demo of FullCalendar:

http://jsfiddle.net/k5de79b3/

```
           eventDrop: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,allDay,revertFunc) {
                var eventData = {};
                eventData.event_id = event.id;
                eventData.start = event.start.toDate();

                var year = eventData.start.getUTCFullYear();
                var month = eventData.start.getUTCMonth() + 1;
                var day = eventData.start.getUTCDate();
                var hours = eventData.start.getUTCHours();
                var minutes = eventData.start.getUTCMinutes();
                var seconds = eventData.start.getUTCSeconds();
                if(month < 10){ month = '0' + month; }
                if(day < 10){ day = '0' + day; }
                if(hours < 10){ hours = '0' + hours; }
                if(minutes < 10){ minutes = '0' + minutes; }
                if(seconds < 10){ seconds = '0' + seconds; }

                eventData.start = year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
                alert(eventData.start);
            }
```

to show how the date/time being returned for the dropped event is misleading.

The drop handler is setup to return the UTC datetime of the dropped event. Yet you'll notice that if you drop an event on **11/10/2014 08:00:00**, that is the time that is returned.

I am in Pacific time zone (**-8**) so if I'm using the calendar and drop an event on **2pm** (my local time) shouldn't the UTC time returned be **10pm**?

Has anyone else noticed this behavior?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the results you want, you need to add `timezone:'local'` when you initialize the calendar.

The default for `timezone` in FullCalendar is "no timezone", [as specified in the docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/). So no, it isn't accounting for your local time.

View the differences using [this more-readable version of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/k5de79b3/3/) as you posted (no timezone) against [a version where it will use your local timezone](http://jsfiddle.net/k5de79b3/5/).

Comment: timezone:'local' saved me. I thought that just setting the Locale would work.